# Trying to make 2 following elements of a list into a seperate list

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my current code and the output is

```
['50003252714', 'Malle Kask', 
'40003252714', 'Endel Kask', 
'30003252714', 'Peeter Kask', 
'60003252714', 'JĆ¼ri MĆ¤nd', 
'70003252714', 'Laura MĆ¤nd', 
'80003252714', 'Kerli MĆ¤nd', 
'10003252714', 'Elvo Pikk', 
'20003252714', 'Signal Pikk']
```

What I want to do is make a new list inside the original list with 2 following elements. An example of what I want as an end result is

```
[["50003252714","Malle Kask"],
["40003252714","Endel Kask"],
[...]]
```

I tried using for and while loops inside each other but it got really messy and I didn't get my desired result.

```
nimedFail = open("nimed.txt")
lapsedFail = open("lapsed.txt")

def seosta_lapsed_ja_vanemad(lapsed,nimed):
    nimed = []
    lapsed = []
    eraldatud_nimed_töötlemata = []
    eraldatud_nimed = []
    eraldatud_nimed_listides = []

    for rida in nimedFail:
        nimed.append(rida.strip())
    for rida in lapsedFail:
        lapsed.append(rida.strip())
    for ele in nimed:
        eraldatud_nimed_töötlemata.append(ele.split(" "))
    for ele in eraldatud_nimed_töötlemata:
        x = " ".join(ele[1:3])
        eraldatud_nimed.append(ele[0])
        eraldatud_nimed.append(x)


    return eraldatud_nimed


print(seosta_lapsed_ja_vanemad("nimed.txt","lapsed.txt"))
```

Comment: could you clarify: you load two files, one of which contains numbers and the other contains names; and now you want to combine the content in a list of lists (each entry holding a number and a name)?

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough, and the code has some basic issues. For example, why are you passing the file names to `nimed` and `lapsed`, when they are reinitialized to empty lists at start of the function. 

Please post a small snippet from nimed.txt and lapsed.txt files, and a sample output of what you want.

Comment: Pretty much one file consists of a number(social security number), a space and then the name of the person(nimed.txt). The other file contains a social security number of a parent, a space and then the social security number of the parent's child(lapsed.txt).  The end result should be where every child has their parents listed after them after a colon.  You understood it correctly though yes that I want to have a list of a number and name in a bigger list.

Comment: alright, I posted two lines of code what I think you can do in principle - however, if you add an example line of each input file, I can clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is my way of doing this:

```
list = ['50003252714', 'Malle Kask',
'40003252714', 'Endel Kask',
'30003252714', 'Peeter Kask',
'60003252714', 'JĆ¼ri MĆ¤nd',
'70003252714', 'Laura MĆ¤nd',
'80003252714', 'Kerli MĆ¤nd',
'10003252714', 'Elvo Pikk',
'20003252714', 'Signar Pikk']
```

Convert the list using **iter()** and then within the loop use **next()** iterator:

```
it = iter(a)
final = []
for a in it:
    list_of_two = [a, next(it)]
    final.append(list_of_two)
print(final)
```

**Output:**

```
[['50003252714', 'Malle Kask'], ['40003252714', 'Endel Kask'], ['30003252714', 'Peeter Kask'], ['60003252714', 'JĆ¼ri MĆ¤nd'], ['70003252714', 'Laura MĆ¤nd'], ['80003252714', 'Kerli MĆ¤nd'], ['10003252714', 'Elvo Pikk'], ['20003252714', 'Signar Pikk']]
```

Comment: Please don't redefine the built-in `list`! and what about `final = [l[i:i+2] for i in range(len(l), 2)]`? - 1-liner, easy to read...

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar idea to this in my mind but I didn't know of the iter function so I tried to do it with a combination of loops. This got me my desired result.

Comment: Why this level of complication? Why not just zip?

Comment: like `[[a, b] for a, b in zip(l[0::2], l[1::2])]`?

Answer (score 1):

you can likely create the combined list / list of lists already when reading the files, something along the lines of

```py
with open("nimed.txt", 'r') as nimedFail, open("lapsed.txt", 'r') as lapsedFail:
    l_out = [[a.strip(), b.strip()] for a, b in zip(nimedFail, lapsedFail) if a.strip() and b.strip()]
```

Comment: Wow, I should've thought of that. Makes things a lot simpler. Thank you!

Comment: note that if you want to select only certain parts from each line of the input files, you'll have to select these - similar to how you do it in your code

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the variable names but I'll try to code it.

```
def seosta_lapsed_ja_vanemad(lapsed,nimed):
    with open(lapsed, 'r') as lapsed_file_handler:
        lapsed_content = lapsed_file_handler.readlines()
    with open(nimed, 'r') as nimed_file_handler:
        nimed_content = nimed_file_handler.readlines()
```

Assuming both files are equal in line numbers, you may just loop through them:

```
    return [[lapsed_content[i], nimed_content[i]] for i in range(0, len(lapsed_content))]
```

I suggest you use tuple or dictionary instead of nested list.